# how can I get s3 bucket's list of object using prefix

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, listobject

Using this script, I find a list of objects that have this prefix and delimiter.  However, right now, I am not able to do that one with the same script. Can anyone help me or give me any other way to do this task?

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'demo',
    Delimiter: 12345,
    Prefix: 'upload/',
};

s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Finally", data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide with a snippet of the response data.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Does the code you posted work? Or are you running it with different params (delimiter and prefix separately)? What does the response look like? Any errors?

Comment: y you put delimiter 12345? cloud you please share s3 object structure

Comment: delimiter should be / slash